# how to migrate products from Magento 1.x to Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I would like to know if I can design a process to **insert products** from **Magento 1.x to Magento 2**, using Magento ORM.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the data-migration-tool for that: https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool

However you may find the answer for your question within the code of the migration tool: https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/blob/master/src/Migration/Step/Eav/Data.php